# Renaming multiple folders with a different naming scheme

Tags: batch-file

I have a LOT of folders for pictures that I have named by date, with the date in the form of 03282013, meaning March 28 2013.

I have started using a more obvious, and easy to sort, naming scheme of 2013-03-28, meaning March 28 2013.

Is there a straight forward way, using a batch file, to rename all my old folders using the new format?

Example: Rename 03282013 to 2013-03-28 and so forth

Comment: Using PowerShell or a first-class programming language (where string manipulation is better) would probably work better for this.  That said: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: Need more information - do the target directories have "mmddyyyy" as their name or is that just PART of the name? If its just a part, what is the naming pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, remove the last `echo` (before `ren`), if the output is OK:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('for /f "delims=" %%i in ^('dir /ad /b .^^^| findstr /b [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$'^) do ^
@set "fname=%%i"^&^
@call set "month=%%fname:~0,2%%"^&^
@call set "day=%%fname:~2,2%%"^&^
@call set "year=%%fname:~-4%%"^&^
@call set "fname=%%year%%-%%month%%-%%day%%"^&^
@call echo "%%~i" "%%fname%%"') do echo ren "%%~a" "%%~b"
```

This searches for folders in the right MMDDYYYY format, all other folders stay unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below renames all folders in current directory from MMDDYYYY format into YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   set name=%%a
   ren %%a !name:~4!-!name:~0,2!-!name:~2,2!
)
```

Antonio